# Masking 4D numpy array with 3D mask

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 4D numpy array D with shape nx,ny,nz,nt and a 3D numpy mask M with shape nx,ny,nz.  I wish to set each element of D with index ix,iy,iz,: to 0 if M[ix,iy,iz] is False.  How do I do this?

Comment: Please post your code and input and expected output.

Comment: In your question, what is `it`? Should the relation hold true for any `it`, aka `N[ix,iy,iz,:] = 0` if `M[ix,iy,iz]` is `False` ?

Comment: Yes Seon that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and broadcasting:

```
import numpy as np

arr  = np.random.randint(10, size=(4, 2, 3, 5))
mask = np.random.choice([True, False], size=(4, 2, 3))

out = np.where(mask[..., None], arr, 0)
```

Note that in the above, `mask[..., None]` adds a single dimension to the end, so its shape is `(4, 2, 3, 1)` which broadcasts nicely with the shape of `arr`.

PS: Depending on your code you may be able to retain such a single dimension with `keepdims=True` if you derive your `mask` from `arr`. That would save you the explicit `[..., None]`.

---

EDIT: This should work just fine too:

```
arr[~mask, :] = 0
```